# Error Message The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, cart

i'm newbie in laravel i'm trying to create a shopping cart using this package bumbummen99/shoppingcart via car-booking view when i add the car to the cart it works so every thing works fine so far but when i want to go to cart route it gives me this error this is my code

the cart root

```
Route::post('/cart', 'App\Http\Controllers\CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
```

this where the root where display my cars and the add to cart button

```
Route::get('/car-booking/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CarController@showbooking')->name('car-booking');
```

```
@if($cart->where('id', $car->id)->count())
    <p class="rental-tag">In Cart</p>
       @else
    <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }}" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="car_id" value="{{$car->id}}">
      @csrf
      
    <button type="submit" class="gauto-theme-btn"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Add to cart</button>
    </form>
  <br>
 @endif
```

i don't think that there is any problem here, those are the controllers

the action in the car controller

```
public function showbooking($id){
        
        $car = Car::find($id);
        $cart = Cart::content();
        //dd($cart);
        return view('car/car-booking', ['car' => $car], ['cart' => $cart]);
    }
```

the action in the cart controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $car = Car::findOrFail($request->input('car_id'));
        Cart::add(
            $car->id, 
            $car->brand->brand_name , 
            1, $car->price /100,
        );

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'successfully added');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the same URL as `/cart` with `get` method?

Comment: no i have only one url to the cart  `/cart`

Comment: Did you try to clear the config?

Comment: no i don't know how to do that is it a command or something related to cart.php in config folder

Comment: if you mean the route:clear i already tried it

Answer (score 0):

You have `Route::post('/cart', ..` in your code

your error

> The Get Method is not supported for this route

says it all.

you need to register a get route to visit `/cart`

create one something like

`Route::get('/cart', ..Controller@Function)`

visit [Laravel Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) to know more

Comment: when i do so it gives me 404 not found page

Comment: can you share the code for the route which you created for cart

Comment: i replaced post with get `Route::get('/cart', 'App\Http\Controllers\CartController@store')->name('cart.store');` in case of post it gives me the error in the title in case of get it return page 404

Comment: why did you use the `store` method if you are creating a get request? you should use a different method instead
store method is supposed to store the cart details in the database and get method is supposed to show the carts after fetching from the database

Comment: do you want to see what is in the cart ? or you need to store data in the cart?

Comment: no the data storing is working just fine what i want is to see what is in the cart i'm really trapped here

Comment: i'm thinking that i have to create a new route with a new method

Comment: okay so don't use store method for the get request, leave your `post('/cart'` as it is, create a new route as `Route::get('/cart', ...User your new controller method here ...)`

Comment: in the new method try dumping the data after fetching form the db
use `dd($carts)` and see if your page renders the cart details

Comment: yes it return the array with all the items in the car thank you